# JSONobject responses to String

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I get data from a mysql database and textView them just to make sure I got them. Problem is I can't figure a way to actually use them. eg I want to check if the Code the user inserts equals the code I get from the db. This is the JSON part of the Code.

```js
private void showJSON(String response){
        String Code="";
        String Latitude="";
        String Longitude="";
        String Information= "";
        String Question= "";
        String Answer1= "";
        String Answer2= "";
        String Answer3= "";
        String Answer4= "";
        String RightAnswer= "";
        String Trigger= "";
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
            JSONObject tripData = result.getJSONObject(0);
            Code = tripData.getString(Config.KEY_CODE);
            Latitude = tripData.getString(Config.KEY_LATITUDE);
            Longitude = tripData.getString(Config.KEY_LONGITUDE);
            Information = tripData.getString(Config.KEY_INFORMATION);
            Question = tripData.getString(Config.KEY_QUESTION);
            Answer1 = tripData.getString(Config.KEY_ANSWER1);
            Answer2 = tripData.getString(Config.KEY_ANSWER2);
            Answer3 = tripData.getString(Config.KEY_ANSWER3);
            Answer4 = tripData.getString(Config.KEY_ANSWER4);
            RightAnswer = tripData.getString(Config.KEY_RIGHTANSWER);
            Trigger = tripData.getString(Config.KEY_TRIGGER);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        textViewResult.setText("Code:\t" + Code + "\nLatitude:\t" + Latitude + "\nLongitude:\t" + Longitude + "\nInformation:\t" + Information + "\nQuestion:\t" + Question + "\nAnswer1:\t" + Answer1 + "\nAnswer2:\t" + Answer2 + "\nAnswer3:\t" + Answer3 + "\nAnswer4:\t" + Answer4 + "\nRightAnswer:\t" + RightAnswer + "\nTrigger:\t" + Trigger);
    }
```

Comment: "the Code the user inserts" - inserts where?

Comment: In the same activity the user types a Code. eg editTextCode. I want to check if that is the same with the tripData.getString(Config.KEY_CODE)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this user entered "code" is a string on a edittext.

edittext.getText().toString().equals("code from response")

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The user entered "code" is indeed a string on a edittext. What should put in the "code from responce" part of your answer?

Comment: Assuming this is the response from the JSON "Code = tripData.getString(Config.KEY_CODE);" The "Code from Response" is the Code String object.